# 500, 502 , 503 & 504 errors for spring boot app deployed on azure

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, azure, azure-web-app-service

I recently deployed my spring boot app on azure. The steps that I took was to create a resource group in Azure then created a web app service for my spring boot app. My app uses postgresql db so I created one using Azure Database for PostgreSQL single server. The code was deployed via the deployment center in azure. The source was Github and the build provider was GitHub Actions. I checked the logs to see if there were any issues or errors with the deployment but everything was successful.

Seeing as I am just testing my app, there isn't any issue of running out of space or too much requests hitting the backend url. I am using Standard S1(App Service Plan) for both my backend and frontend application. My frontend application is in angular and that was deployed successfully as well seeing as I was able to navigate to it when the deployment was complete, however, that is not the same for my spring boot app whenever I tried to navigate to its url as well as one of the endpoints that I have configured for public access(permitAll).

Can anyone please point out what I might be doing wrong or what I did not do?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out what was cause of my problem. It turns out that I did not turn on
"Allow access to Azure services" in Azure. [image]